# Flip Image in Processing 3.4

Tags: processing

How can I flip (mirror) an image along the Y-axis in Processing 3.4? I have tried `scale(-1,1)` but that just makes my image disappear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `scale(-1, 1)` then your X values are flipped, and you have to adjust your arguments accordingly. Here's an example:

```
size(500, 500);
PImage img = loadImage("my_image.jpg");
scale(-1, 1);
image(img, -500, 0, width, height);
```

Personally I find this very confusing, so I would avoid calling `scale()` with negative numbers. There are a number of ways to flip an image: I would probably use the `get()` function to get the colors from the image and copy them into a `PGraphics` instance.